# How to Insert spaces in the whole string among characters except ANYTHING which looks like \something, using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `s = '{qcos\\theta_{g}\\over r})^{2\\over 1 + \\alpha^{2}}}\\ 1234'`

and if I use the regex `(?<=.)(?!$)` [as I have used in this example](https://regex101.com/r/wH1nK1/1), it gives me the whole string split in white characters. But I want to preserve anything `\wordonly` so for example in the above given string, I want the answer to be

`'{ q c o s \\theta _ { g } \\over r } ) ^ { 2 \\over 1 + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } } \\ 1 2 3 4'`

where `\theta` remains the same but `123` becomes `1 2 3`, `abc` becomes `a b c` and `\theta_{21}` becomes `\theta _ { 2 1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s = '{qcos\\theta_{g}\\over r})^{2\\over 1 + \\alpha^{2}}}\\ 1234'
print( ' '.join(re.findall(r'\\[a-zA-Z]*|\S', s)) )
# => { q c o s \theta _ { g } \over r } ) ^ { 2 \over 1 + \alpha ^ { 2 } } } \ 1 2 3 4
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/H5MYcZ).

With `re.findall(r'\\[a-zA-Z]*|\S', s)`, you get a list of `\`+letters and any single non-whitespace chars.

Then, all you need is to join the found items with a space, `' '.join(...)`.

*Regex details*:

- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `\S` -  any non-whitespace char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wi8yOl/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. Just one more thing, if I want it to be `qcos` instead of `q c o s` means preserve spaces between alphabets ONLY and everything else remains the same as you have just described?

Comment: @Deshwal Got new requirements? :) You can match an optional ``\`` and then one or more letters to keep them spelt solidly with `' '.join(re.findall(r'\\?[a-zA-Z]+|\S', s))`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Js5ica).

Comment: Lol yeah. Just trying out aspects. Thanks a lot.